# Adding Image to google slide from google drive or local stored one

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

getting "Invalid requests[0].createImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden."
on adding image from google drive to google slides
Here below the code snippet I've tried
although making the image public through advanced sharing option.
the service account has edit access to the slide I want to add image to it.

---

```
import section: add here the required dependencies
# python build-in modules
import json
import time
import io
# external modules

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
# user modules
from via_types import BasePlugin


class GoogleSlidesPlugin(BasePlugin):
    """
    this plugin allows to communicate with Google API and Google Spreadsheets
    by using the already created credentials
    """

    def __init__(self):
        BasePlugin.__init__(self)

        self.Scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly']

        self.Creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            r'Libraries/credentials/lucky-dahlia-268410-c4c0c57c1908.json', self.Scopes)
        

        self.service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=self.Creds)
        self.drive = build('drive',  'v3', credentials=self.Creds)

        
    
    def add_images_to_gslides(self, args):
        """
        Adds a new worksheet to a spreadsheet.

        :param args:    [0]: Presentation
                        [1]: images array Paths
                        [2]: slide number to insert images
        :param uid: this value is automatically generated for groped steps

        :return: the detail and status execution of plugin
        """

        # start results to report to output
        self.response.status = 'pass'
        self.response.details = 'image/s was/were added to slides'

    
        try:
            # try to store the passed arguments0
            presentation_id = args[0]
        except Exception as e:
            # if there is a missed argument the command is going to end its exec
            # store the results to report in output
            self.response.status = 'fail'
            self.response.details = 'some argument was missed'
            return self.response

        try:
            # open connection with an specific GSlide 
            
          
            presentation = self.service.presentations().get(presentationId=presentation_id).execute()
            slides = presentation.get('slides')

            print('The presentation contains {} slides:'.format(len(slides)))
            for i, slide in enumerate(slides):
                print('- Slide #{} contains {} elements.'.format(
                    i + 1, len(slide.get('pageElements'))))

           
            IMG_FILE = args[1]
            try : 
                print('** Searching for icon file')
                rsp = self.drive.files().list(q="name='%s'" % IMG_FILE).execute().get('files')[0]
                print(' - Found image %r' % rsp['name'])            
                IMAGE_URL = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + rsp['id']
                #IMAGE_URL = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/'+rsp['id']+ '/edit'
                
            except Exception as e:
                file_metadata = {'name': IMG_FILE}
                media = MediaFileUpload(IMG_FILE, mimetype='image/png')        
            
                upload = self.drive.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='webContentLink, id, webViewLink').execute()
                fileId = upload.get('id')
                IMAGE_URL = upload.get('webContentLink')                
                self.drive.permissions().create(fileId=fileId, body={'type': 'anyone','role': 'writer'}).execute()

           
            
            
            print(IMAGE_URL)
            requests = []
            image_id = 'MyImage_02'
            page_id = slide['objectId']
            emu4M = {
                'magnitude': 4000000,
                'unit': 'EMU'
            }
            requests.append({
                'createImage': {
                    'objectId': image_id,
                    'url': IMAGE_URL,
                    'elementProperties': {
                        'pageObjectId': page_id,
                        'size': {
                            'height': emu4M,
                            'width': emu4M
                        },
                        'transform': {
                            'scaleX': 1,
                            'scaleY': 1,
                            'translateX': 100000,
                            'translateY': 100000,
                            'unit': 'EMU'
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

            body = {                
                'requests': requests
            }
            response = self.service.presentations() \
                .batchUpdate(presentationId=presentation_id, body=body ).execute()
            create_image_response = response.get('replies')[0].get('createImage')
            print('Created image with ID: {0}'.format(
                create_image_response.get('objectId')))
        except Exception as e:
            self.response.status = 'fail'
            self.response.details = e
            

        return self.response




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # use_the_main_function_to_test_your_plugin_without_using_a_sequence
    plugin_template = GoogleSlidesPlugin()

    plugin_template.add_images_to_gslides([presentationID,'image.png'])
    print(plugin_template.response.status,
          plugin_template.response.details)
```

Comment: Which does your issue occur using `google drive` or `local stored one`?

Comment: using google drive.

Comment: Does the service account have edit access to the image you want to insert?

Comment: Yes, I've uploaded it to drive of service account to be sure that it has access to.

Comment: What if you upload the image to your drive, but share it with the service account?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `using google drive.`, can I ask you about the permissions of the file of `IMAGE_URL = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + rsp['id']`?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for replying , I've tried this and the result was 
 "Invalid requests[0].createImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden."

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to find a way to upload images to Google Slides using Python. I created a program that uploads images to Google Cloud Storage (instead of Google Drive); creates a signed URL for them; then uses that URL to import images into Google Slides. It's available [here](https://github.com/kburchfiel/google_slides_image_uploader) under the MIT License and may be a helpful tool/resource.